# MVVM move RibbonTabs into separate viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, ribbon

I use Windows Ribbon for WPF with Caliburn Micro. Is it possible to move `RibbonTabs` into different views with ViewModels so views can be more readable?

I have `MainToolbarViewModel` class bound with a `MainToolbarView`.

**MainToolbarViewModel**:

```
    public TabViewModel Tab { get; set; }

    public MainToolbarViewModel()
    {
        this.Tab = new TabViewModel();
    }
```

**MainToolbarView**:

```
    <ribbon:Ribbon HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="0">
        <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="../Resources/WindowsIcons/help.png"></RibbonButton>
        </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>

        <ContentControl x:Name="Tab"></ContentControl>

    </ribbon:Ribbon>
```

I want the `ContentControl` to work as a `RibbonTab`. This approach works well with standard controls, but with ribbon it just simply doesn't show anything.

**TabViewModel**:

```
    public class TabViewModel : Screen
    {
        public TabViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "New Tab";
        }
    }
```

**TabView**:

```
<UserControl ......>
    <RibbonTab IsSelected="True" Header="{Binding DisplayName}">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Types">
            <RibbonButton Content="Test"></RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</UserControl>
```

I read about making ViewModels for RibbonTab, RibbonGroup, RibbonButton but this just seems crazy, because I would need to create ViewModel for every control.

Additionally most of the answers I read were at least 1 year old. Anything changed since? What is the easiest way to move `RibbonTabs` to a different viewmodel?

**UPDATE:**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Tab"></ContentControl>
```

Renders `RibbonTab`'s content inside its header, so basically I have `RibbonGroup`
inside `RibbonTab`'s header.
I think it's because `Ribbon` treats `<ContentControl>` as a header of some sort rather than `RibbonTab`.

Comment: For this scenario, could you bypass Caliburn all together and just do <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Tab"} /> ?

Comment: I updated my question. I tested your solution and now nothing renders at all. I don't think caliburn micro is involved in this issue.